# wrong number arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

Looks like rspec is not passing any arguments to the method, even though they're written in the spec file.

The method:

```
def echo(msg)
  msg
end
```

The test:

```
require './echo.rb'

describe echo do
  it 'echoes' do
    expect(echo('hello')).to eq('hello')
  end
end
```

terminal output:

```
/home/.../scratch/echo.rb:1:in `echo': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
from /home/.../scratch/scratch_spec.rb:3:in '<top (required)>'
from /home/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in 'load'
...
```

Comment: Seems to work if I also pass the argument in the describe line `describe echo('hello') do`. Is this intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change:

```
describe echo do
```

to:

```
describe 'echo' do
```

i.e. putting the method name as string. Otherwise, it tries to call the `echo` method at this point and you don't pass the argument here and hence you get the mentioned error.

So, this should work perfectly:

```
describe 'echo' do
  it 'echoes' do
    expect(echo('hello')).to eq('hello')    
  end
end
```